# Unrecognized option 'stimeout'

Tags: ffmpeg, timeout

Unrecognized option 'stimeout', is popping up when i'm using the command:

```
ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -y -stimeout 1000000 -i "rtsp://admin:admin123@10.40.20.247:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0&unicast=true&proto=Onvif" -c copy -vsync 1 -f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_atclocktime 0 -segment_list_flags +live -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 "C:\MINDA\OBITS\BlackBox\Recordings\Normal\Dahua-5M02C9FPAG1C78A\2022-1-4\%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S.avi"
```

Comment: I can't find these options anywhere here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Options

Answer (score 5):

The `-stimeout` option for rtsp has been renamed to `-timeout` in ffmpeg 5.0.
This can be verified by comparing the rtsp section of the documentation to an older version:

**Old:** https://web.archive.org/web/20210328173215/https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp

```
stimeout
    Set socket TCP I/O timeout in microseconds.
```

**Current:** https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp

```
timeout
    Set socket TCP I/O timeout in microseconds.
```

The previous rtsp `timeout` option clashed with `timeout` options of other protocol implementations. All had the same name, but for other protocols `timeout` specifies a socket I/O timeout, while for rtsp `timeout` specified the maximum time to wait for incoming connection when ffmpeg is running in rtsp listen mode.

For better compatibility to other protocols, the `timeout` option of the rtsp implementation [has been deprecated in 2018](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commitdiff/ff46124b0df17a1d35249e09ae8eae9a61f16e04?hp=0519e66a90f076591fb35dab1a3ed14204de08c0), and the new option `listen_timeout` has been introduced in its place.
In 2021, [the old option has then finally been removed](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commitdiff/6f34f031908b8f16482e951ee5232116fb42b46a?hp=252500a78fe1a31abc79e6070d16f50382c39343), consequently also renaming the `stimeout` option to `timeout`.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works: change *-stimeout* to *-timeout*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).